# How to make koa wait for a node-sqlite3 result?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, koa

I am using Koa2 with [node-sqlite3](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3) and am running into an issue where I can't get Koa to wait for the db call to return before returning the body

Simplified example:

```
app.get('/:name/:nickname', function (ctx) {
    var queryParams = [ctx.params.name, ctx.params.nickname]
    db.get("SELECT nickname FROM users WHERE name = ? AND nickname = ?", queryParams, function (err,result) {

        if (result == null) {
            console.log('Add new nickname')
            db.run("INSERT INTO users (name, nickname) VALUES (?, ?)", queryParams)
            ctx.body = 'Inserted user ' + ctx.params.nickname
        } else {
            console.log('Return existing nickname')
            ctx.body = result.nickname
        }
    })
    console.log('This is after')
})
```

Which always returns something like:

> This is After
>   Add new nickname

How can I get koa to wait for the sqlite result?

**edit**

My apologies, it is a simple matter of a promise:

```
app.get('/:name/:nickname', async (ctx, next) => {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var queryParams = [ctx.params.name, ctx.params.nickname]
        db.get("SELECT nickname FROM users WHERE name = ? AND nickname = ?", queryParams, function (err,result) {
            if (result == null) {
                // Add the name if not in DB
                db.run("INSERT INTO users (name, nickname) VALUES (?, ?)", queryParams)
                ctx.body = 'Inserted user ' + ctx.params.nickname
            } else {
                // Return nickname if in DB
                ctx.body = row.nickname
            }
            resolve()
        })
    })

    console.log('This is after')
})
```

Comment: Of course it's going to be printed in that order, then code after the callback is being fired before the log statements in the callback. If you want the "this is after" to actually come after you need to move it up a line

Comment: If you resolved it please post that as an answer and not as an edit to the question